# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}((\tan(\frac{\pi}{2n}).....\tan(\frac{n\pi}{2n}))^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Now,
\begin{align}
&\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\tan(\frac{\pi}{2n})}{\frac{\pi}{2n}}\cdots\frac{\tan(\frac{n\pi}{2n})}{\frac{n\pi}{2n}}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\frac{(\pi) }{2n}(1.2.3...n) ^{\frac{1}{n}}\\
&=((1)....(1))^{\frac{1}{n}}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\pi) }{2n}(1)=0.
\end{align}
This has been my answer but the answer given in my book is $\infty$.Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The $\tan(\pi/2)$ term causes the limit to diverge.

Comment: @Integrand isn't it $(\pi)$/2n

Comment: You have $\tan(n\pi/(2n))=\tan(\pi/2)$...

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\tan(\frac{\pi}{2n})....\tan(\frac{n\pi}{2n})\right)^{\dfrac{1}{n}}$$
$$=\exp\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1n\left(\ln\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)+\ldots+\ln\tan\left(\frac{n\pi}{2n}\right)\right)$$

Comment: I don't think that $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2})$is defined

Comment: The product of $\tan(\alpha)$ and $\tan(\pi/2-\alpha)$ equals 1 for any $\alpha\in(0,\pi/2)$, so $$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{\color{red}{n-1}}\tan\frac{\pi k}{2n}\right)^{1/n}=\large{1}.$$ This also is $\exp\int_{0}^{1}\log\tan\frac{\pi x}{2}\,dx$, but there is no need to over-complicate it.